# What could be the cause behind error "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"?

Tags: excel, vba

```
mySValue = InputBox("Enter the no. of rows to be considered")
    Set myrange = Worksheets("UniqueSupNames").Range("A:B")

    For counterSVar = 3 To mySValue
        SupName = Range("A" & counterSVar)
        SupId = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SupName, Range("myrange"), 2, False)
        Range("K" & counterSVar).Value = SupId
    Next counterSVar
```

Above is my code.  Please suggest the solution.
FYI - I have created a worksheet namely "UniqueSupNames" (in the same workbook) which contains two columns (A & B) containing Supplier Name and Supplier IDs respectively.

Answer (score 2):

With `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, you'll get a breaking error when there's no match.  So, when the error isn't handled, as in your case, you'll get the error `Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class`.  However, if you use `Application.VLookup` instead, you'll get a *non-breaking* error.  Also, since you've assign your lookup range to `myrange`, `Range("myrange")` should be replaced with `myrange`, as @ARL has already mentioned.  So you should have the following...

```
SupID = Application.VLookup(SupName, myRange, 2, False)
```

Also, you can test for the error using `IsError`...

```
Dim SupID As Variant

SupID = Application.VLookup(SupName, myRange, 2, False)

If IsError(SupID) Then
    MsgBox "No match found!", vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox "SupID: " & SupID, vbInformation
End If
```

Also, if you use `Application.InputBox` instead of the `InputBox` function, you can force the user to enter a number instead of text, etc., and you can test whether the user has cancelled.  For example...

```
Dim mySVAlue As Variant

'prompt the user to enter a number
mySVAlue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the no. of rows to be considered", Type:=1)

'if user cancels, exit the sub
If mySVAlue = False Then Exit Sub
```

So your macro can be re-written as follows...

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub LookupValues()

    'declare the variables
    Dim mySVAlue As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim SupName As String
    Dim SupID As Variant
    Dim counterSVar As Long

    'prompt the user to enter a number
    mySVAlue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the no. of rows to be considered", Type:=1)

    'if user cancels, exit the sub
    If mySVAlue = False Then Exit Sub

    'set the range for the lookup table
    Set myRange = Worksheets("UniqueSupNames").Range("A:B")

    'lookup the values for the user selected rows
    For counterSVar = 3 To mySVAlue
        SupName = Range("A" & counterSVar).Value
        SupID = Application.VLookup(SupName, myRange, 2, False)
        Range("K" & counterSVar).Value = SupID
    Next counterSVar

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

myrange is already a range, so range("myrange") maybe where your issue lies. Try this-

```
For counterSVar = 3 To mySValue
    SupName = Range("A" & counterSVar)
    SupId = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SupName, myrange, 2, False)
    Range("K" & counterSVar).Value = SupId
Next counterSVar
```

Comment: You are correct.  Initially I tried that only but its still throwing the same error.

Comment: @UmeshGanoo What is the format of the SupName cells? There might be a type issue or a file path issue. Also, what line do you get the error on?